# RSA Encryption using PL/SQL or Cobol

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cobol

I would like to encrypt a String before sending it over to my client.
The client has given me a RSA Public Key.
There is a 512 bytes of Modulus and 6 bytes of Pub. Exp. (all Hex).

Normally I am running Cobol to produce this output file. But I dont think Cobol has any api/call to encrypt.
So I was planning of calling an Oracle procedure/function to do this.

**Question:** How can I encrypt a string using RSA public key in Oracle PL/SQL (or SQL)?

Comment: Have you considered using Java or C stored procesures?

Comment: It might help if you listed your platform.  If you are on z, for example, you could either embed a call to a jar or use ICSF...

Comment: but Cobol on any platform will support what you need for encryption: exponent and modulo operations.

Comment: As suggested by @miraclefoxx, we now made a Java Servlet which returns encrypted String. This servlet is then called from Oracle PL/SQL. Thanks a lot for everybody's help.

Comment: crypto4ora can solve your problem. https://github.com/atul19971/crypto4ora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSA key used in asymmetric encryption. Oracle provides asymmetric encryption in two points:

- When transferring data between the client and the database
- For user authentication

And for it requires the [Oracle Advanced Security Option](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-security/index.html).
This addition is simply executed in two cases that described above and not provides API.

Oracle provides tools for symmetric encryption - look in package [DBMS_CRYPTO](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_crypto.htm#i1004148). Also you can use stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial DidiSoft ORA_PGP package offers suitable method illustrated below:

```
DECLARE
  public_key_modulus CLOB := 'c24e5473164291964e247b179cf7590208bc96140ee6d900f531ce3d8d82b8a89a19e8c238222b8d10d943cdc6006adf094c84ca40a74d7e3abe91da690e72d399e79423826d95cd3a2f5b832e38b586078ddf5e6dea0ded39fd221d5772b7876295c1c36a79c253476e5344d7861e8e2bf1c71edc19ee57310a8e4d83350397';
  public_key_exponent CLOB := '10001';

  encrypted_data raw(32000);
BEGIN
  -- RSA Encrypt
  encrypted_data := ORA_RSA.ENCRYPT_WITH_MODULUS(message => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('Hello World', 'AL32UTF8'),
                         public_key_modulus => DBMS_LOB.substr(public_key_modulus), 
                         public_key_exponent => DBMS_LOB.substr(public_key_exponent));  
END;
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft.